# ADODataSet Delphi Edit

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

Tenho um `ADODataSet` com a seguinte consulta

```
DECLARE @ID_CONTRATO_EMPRESARIAL INTEGER = :ID_CONTRATO_EMPRESARIAL
BEGIN
WITH V1 AS (
select C.ID_CONTRATO, 
    COUNT(CASE AD.FUNCIONARIO WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) FUNCIONARIOS,
    COUNT(*) MEMBROS
FROM CONTRATO C, ADESAO AD
WHERE C.ID_CONTRATO_EMPRESARIAL = @ID_CONTRATO_EMPRESARIAL  
    AND C.ID_CONTRATO = AD.ID_CONTRATO
GROUP BY C.ID_CONTRATO, C.NUMERO, C.VALOR_CLIENTE)
SELECT 
    V1.FUNCIONARIOS, V1.MEMBROS,
    PT.ID_PESSOA AS ID_PESSOA_TITULAR, PT.NOME AS NOME_TITULAR,
    C.*
FROM V1, CONTRATO C, PESSOA PT
WHERE V1.ID_CONTRATO = C.ID_CONTRATO
    AND C.ID_PESSOA = PT.ID_PESSOA
END
```

Gostaria de saber se tenho como dar um `Edit` nesse `DataSet` e salvar no banco a coluna alterada.

Basicamente o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte

```
    dmContratoEmpresarial.cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos.Edit;
    dmContratoEmpresarial.cdsContratoEmpresarialContratosVALOR_TI.Value := 1000;
    dmFramework.Post(dmContratoEmpresarial.cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos);
```

Onde a coluna `VALOR_TI` está na tabela `CONTRATO`. Porém ao verificar o banco a coluna não foi alterada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Abordagem padrão

A prática geral é: quando deseja-se editar o resultado de uma query envolvendo múltiplas tabelas e atualizar o banco, recupera-se em uma query à parte os registros apenas da tabela a editar.

Ou seja, o mais simples seria você obter nesta query complexa o id do registro que você precisará editar, e então obter este registro a editar numa outra query simples e editá-lo em outro dataset, ou mesmo fazer um comando SQL update diretamente sobre o registro.

## Uma opção

Por outro lado, uma query ADO oferece a propriedade [Unique Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680834(v=vs.85).aspx), na qual você pode especificar a tabela sobre a qual as operações de *insert*, *delete*, e *update* serão aplicadas quando o resultado da query foi obtido de mais de uma tabela. Mais ou menos assim:

```
ADOQuery.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'CONTRATO';
```

Entretanto, como a sua query é bastante complexa, é possível que o ADO não consiga resolvê-la mesmo com esta propriedade setada; daí lhe resta a abordagem padrão.